# How to access form input value in javascript with special characters in input name?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables, input

I have a form for which I cannot change the input value field names.
One such field is in the HTML as follows:

```
<body>
<form id="f" method="get" action="/code/submit.php">
<input type="text" name="var[list]" id="ixv[list]" value="">
<button type="button" title="Save" onclick="check();">
</form>
</body>
```

Now in my javascript, I want to access that input value.
I tried this, and of course it doesn't work since [] looks
like an array in JS.

```
function check() {
var x=var[list].value;
alert(x);
}
```

The problem is that the variable name has [] in it.  How can I get 
that input field value in javascript?

Comment: That's why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html.

Answer (score 2):

this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/mqv82/1/

```
<input type="text" name="var[list]" id="ixv[list]" value="foo">

alert(document.getElementById('ixv[list]').value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("var[list]")[0].value;
```

Comment: this will returns error , `document.getElementsByName` returns a HTMLCollection !

Answer (score 0):

In modern browser, use `querySelectorAll`

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name="var[list]"]')[0].value
```

or if you know id try `getElementById`

```
document.getElementById('ixv[list]').value
```

or `getElementsByName`

```
document.getElementsByName('var[list]')[0] .value
```

Above three will returns same result